# Configure Drupal temporary directory outside of web root

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, centos7, vesta

I am trying to configure the temporary directory on my Drupal install. Previously, I have been on a cPanel shared account, and all I would simply do is add '../tmp' to the settings and it all worked fine. I have recently outgrown my shared account and upgraded to a VPS, with CentOS and VestaCP. Now, when I enter '../tmp' it says that the folder 'does not exist and could not be created.' I have checked, and that folder is indeed there via file manager and FTP, is 755 permissioned etc. No matter what I try, it just doesn't seem to want to acknowledge it is there.

My CentOS and VestaCP installs have had VERY little tweaking, so they are pretty much default installs at the moment. I was advised to try a path such as:

/home/admin/web/MYDOMAIN/tmp

Other attempts have been:

/tmp and /home/admin/web/*/tmp

But they all threw up the same error. If I type just 'tmp', it works fine, but is then obviously within the web root directory, which is not ideal. Help?

Comment: If you had tried everything, i would suggest to check the folder ownership as well. I got the similar issue and providing the ownership of the tmp folder to a user under the www-data usergroup did the work for me.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that to from a post mentioning www-data:www-data but it just gave an error that that user wasn't available. Upon looking, it was then suggested that it should be apache:apache for CentOS. Tried that and although it changed the ownership, it was still not accessible via Drupal

Answer (score 0):

In the end, it turned out that the best way is to use the pre setup and designated tmp folder for the whole install, which is located at /home/admin/tmp. This also allowed for uberCart credit card processing as well, which wasn't available via a normal ../cc either. The folder also allows for directories, so you could separate between domains and requirements, i.e.

/home/admin/tmp/domain.com or /home/admin/tmp/cc/domain.com